# Using return type set by decltype in implementation file as return type in header file

Tags: c++, header-files

I'm using `sqlite_orm` in C++ and am trying to write unit tests, but I can't as I'm using `auto` for the storage type and I get `deduced return type cannot be used before it is assigned` when writing the tests. I get why that is happening, which is why I'm trying to use `decltype` to workout around it. I'm attempting to follow [this guide](https://github.com/fnc12/sqlite_orm/wiki/FAQ) but am having trouble because I don't know how to add `Storage` as the return type in the header file.

Here's the cpp file:

```
#include "../include/sqlite_orm.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>

struct Item {
    int id;
    std::string itemName;
    std::string category;
    int purchaseYear;
    int purchaseMonth;
    int purchaseDay;
    double purchasePrice;
    int count;
    bool usedInLastSixMonths;
    std::string notes;
};

inline auto Database::initStorage() {
    return sqlite_orm::make_storage("db.sqlite",
                                            sqlite_orm::make_table("items",
                                                                   sqlite_orm::make_column("id", &Item::id, sqlite_orm::autoincrement(), sqlite_orm::primary_key()),
                                                                   sqlite_orm::make_column("item_name", &Item::itemName),
                                                                   sqlite_orm::make_column("category", &Item::category),
                                                                   sqlite_orm::make_column("purchase_year", &Item::purchaseYear),
                                                                   sqlite_orm::make_column("purchase_month", &Item::purchaseMonth),
                                                                   sqlite_orm::make_column("purchase_day", &Item::purchaseDay),
                                                                   sqlite_orm::make_column("purchase_price", &Item::purchasePrice),
                                                                   sqlite_orm::make_column("count", &Item::count),
                                                                   sqlite_orm::make_column("used_in_last_six_months", &Item::usedInLastSixMonths, sqlite_orm::default_value(
                                                                           false)),
                                                                   sqlite_orm::make_column("notes", &Item::notes)));
}

Database db;
using Storage = decltype(db.initStorage());  // Get Storage return type
```

And here's the header file:

```
#ifndef NOTCH_DATABASE_H
#define NOTCH_DATABASE_H
#include "string"
#include <vector>

class Database {
public:
    inline auto initStorage();
    int writeDbToDisk(auto storage);
    Storage read(const std::string& file_name);
    int write(const std::string& file_name, std::vector<std::string> payload);
    int open_or_create(const std::string& file_name);
};


#endif //NOTCH_DATABASE_H
```

What I expected to do is use the `Storage` type from the cpp file as the return type in the header file, but apparently it doesn't work that way. Is there any way to pass the type that is set by `decltype` in my cpp file to the header file?

Comment: Why don't you just name the correct type explicitly? Or move your function definition to the header file?

Comment: The actual return type is `sqlite_orm::internal::storage_t<sqlite_orm::internal::table_t< {stuff }, sqlite_orm::internal::column_t< {...} }` and is quite long, otherwise I'd do that. 

Moving the function definition to the header file is a great idea. I'll give that a shot. Thanks! I'm new to C++.